# Javascript restricting to numbers, only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Using some very basic code such as (from another Stackoverflow question)

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
       <!--
       function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
       //-->
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" 
           type="text" name="txtChar">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I've found that this code works beautifully when you are just inputting numbers. However, it seems to block copy/paste/select all functionally on Firefox, Safari, Opera (can't test IE since I'm running OSX 10.8.3) but it doesn't on Chrome. I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

I've also tried the Jquery AlphaNum library

https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum

But that also exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: if you press ctrl+c its not in b/w 31-57 so the function will return false. and it will not be processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cut, copy, paste, and select all commands will work if you select it from the context menu (i.e. right-clicking on the text box and selecting the appropriate command).

However, the reason why Ctrl+X, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl+A do not work is they are also key events which are blocked by your function. When you press a key and it isn't a number, your function returns `false`.

The following code (from your post) blocks the input:

```
if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
```

The keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+X/C/V/A) have charCodes that are not in these range. You need to whitelist these commands by using the `evt.ctrlKey` property.

Comment: So why does it work in Chrome then? Does Chrome register the key event differently? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Each browser is free to register the events in any order.

Comment: That's a possibility. Here are two resources explaining how these browsers behave: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Answer (score 1):

To allow copy paste:

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
   {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && !evt.ctrlKey  //ctrlKey returns boolean weather ctrl is pressed or not.
         return false;

      return true;
   }
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, this doesn't work on Firefox/Opera/Safari. But does in Chrome. At least on my machine running OSX.

Comment: if you are implementing onkeypress for detecting number then don't allow copy paste.otherwise it will be a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function isNumber(e) {
        e = e || event;
        return +(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.keyCode)) 
                || !e.charCode && e.keyCode < 48;
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XRFHX/)

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox for MacOS, you need to also check the `e.metaKey` attribute which corresponds to the `cmd` key.

This is now fixed in [jquery.alphanum V1.0.9](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum) and the issue you described is logged as [Issue #9](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum/issues/9).